# (C++) | Error when trying to call a function

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, sfml

I wanted to call onStartup() method in a vector. Error C2259 (Visual Studio) shows when compilling (C2259: Cannot instantiate abstract class). Object will be a parent class.
I also tried to remove "virtual" keyword from onStartup(), onUpdate() and onShutDown(), it didn't work.

object.h:

```
class Object : public sf::Transformable, public sf::Drawable
{
public:
    /// (...)

    //class constructor and destructor
    Object();
    virtual ~Object();
    void init(string texturePath);

    virtual void onStartup();
    virtual void onUpdate(); //once per frame
    virtual void onShutdown();
};

//object startup, update and shutdown vectors and its handlers
static std::vector <Object> startupVector;
static std::vector <Object> updateVector;
static std::vector <Object> shutdownVector;

void startupVectorHandler();
void updateVectorHandler();
void shutdownVectorHandler();
```

object.cpp:

```
void Object::init(string texturePath)
{
    //drawing code (...)

    //adding to vector
    startupVector.push_back(*this);
    updateVector.push_back(*this);
    shutdownVector.push_back(*this);
    drawingVector.push_back(Object::s); //rendering queue
}

void startupVectorHandler()
{
    for (auto iter = std::begin(startupVector); iter != std::end(startupVector); iter++)
    {
        iter->onStartup();
    }
}
```

EDIT (I didn't ask my question properly)
Also some more errors occured:
Error   C2672   'std::construct_at': no matching overloaded function found  Gra E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\xmemory   677

Error   C2783   '_Ty *std::construct_at(_Ty *const ,_Types &&...) noexcept()': could not deduce template argument for ''  Gra E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\xmemory   677

Error   C2259   'Object': cannot instantiate abstract class Gra E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\xmemory   674

Thanks for your help! Karol

Comment: Which line of code produces the error? I can't see an instantiation of an `Object` in the code you've provided

Comment: Do you know what an _abstract class_ is?  No code here identifies a class as _abstract_, but the error message states that there is one.

Comment: Error shows in "xmemory" file (probably one of the std libraries?) in line 674. I didn't link that library in my code (i tried, nothing changed. i also tried to add <memory>, result is the same).

Comment: @Karol739 I suspect you are not showing the _complete_ error here.  Can you [edit] your question to include the entire message?

Comment: I don't think you want to create vectors of the base class `Object`. Probably you will want to store references rather than objects, which will allow the vectors to store objects of classes derived from `Object`

Comment: Also some more errors occured:
C2672 (xmemory file, line 677)
C2783 (xmemory file, line 677)

Maybe I should use noexcept keyword?
I'll provide exact info, when I switch VS language to English

Comment: A `std::vector<Object>` can only store `Object`s in it. It can't store derived classes of `Object`. Try `std::vector<Object*>` - or, if you understand unique_ptr, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>`

Comment: @user253751, using std::vector<Object*> generates some errors:
Error C2839 invalid return type 'Object **' for overloaded 'operator ->' Gra C:\Users\swini\source\repos\Gra\src\assets_def\object.cpp 28
Error C2039 'onStartup': is not a member of 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>' Gra C:\Users\swini\source\repos\Gra\src\assets_def\object.cpp 28 

I also changed this* to this. 

This line generates errors: iter->onStartup();